# Achieving communication between main c++ program and embedded ECL

Tags: c++, lisp, embedding

I'm trying to extend a c++ 3d simulation I'm working on with a second language (at the moment ECL) to dynamically influence it at runtime. That is, I want to be able to have a script like this evaluated:
    (move object x y)
that will move "object" to the position (x,y).

The problem is that in order for this to work the ECL environment needs to call some c++ member function of e.g. an instance of the corresponding node of the object to move it.
Now I know how to embed for example ECL and have arbitrary code evaluated and also how to call plain c functions from some library, but I don't see how I can tell the ECL environment about specific instances and how to call their methods.

I suppose this a common thing (if not with ECL) to do and yet I haven't been able to find any information how to do this when the main program is written in c++ and uses some OO.

Comment: Usually, the way you make native functions available to embedded languages is by registering a function pointer with the embedded language runtime. You can either try using a pointer-to-member-function (don't forget the secret `this` argument), or you could write a free wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a command line interface for the C++ application and then communicate via pipe.
That is what I do. Its straightforward and for me it is fast enough.